# Supervised fine tuning in pre-trained language model

Tags: nlp, transformer-model, language-model, fine-tuning

Supervised find turning adds a extra output layer to the pre-trained model.

Does this extra layer alter the probability of words that are not related to the fine tune data?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question.?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.